# Saving/Loading files on Meta Quest 2 in UnityEngine

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine, save, oculusquest

i am working on an app for Meta Quest 2. I have two apps basically. One called "ADMIN" and the other called "CLIENT". You can configure and save some data in the "ADMIN" app and then you should load them in the "CLIENT" app.
The problem is, when i try to read the file in the "CLIENT" app it throws out an error : "UnauthorizedAccessException Access to path storage/emulated/0/Documents is denied" even though i have setted up all permissions correctly.

My Saving Code is :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Android;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;


/// <summary>
/// Save System.
/// Use these APIs to Save/Load game data.
/// </summary>
public static class SaveSystem
{

    private static string selectedFilePath;
    private static ISaveSystemSerializer m_Serializer = new SaveSystemJsonSerializer();
    private static Encoding m_Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the serializer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The serializer.</value>
    public static ISaveSystemSerializer Serializer
    {
        get => m_Serializer ??= new SaveSystemJsonSerializer();
        set => m_Serializer = value;
    }

        

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the encoding.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The encoding.</value>
    public static Encoding DefaultEncoding
    {
        get => m_Encoding ??= Encoding.UTF8;
        set => m_Encoding = value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this <see cref="FG_Saving.SaveSystem"/> encrypt data by default.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> if encode; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    public static bool Encode { get; set; } = false;

    public static string Path { get; set; } = "storage/emulated/0/Documents";


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the encryption password.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The encryption password.</value>
    public static string EncodePassword { get; set; } = "dabkaksdksadkj";

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this <see cref="FG_Saving.SaveSystem"/> log error.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> if log error; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    public static bool LogError { get; set; } = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// Saves data using the identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="identifier">Identifier.</param>
    /// <param name="obj">Object to save.</param>
    /// <param name="saveFile"> Save File Number</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The 1st type parameter.</typeparam>
    public static void Save<T>(string identifier, T obj, int saveFile)
    {
        Save<T>(identifier, obj, saveFile, Encode, EncodePassword, Serializer, DefaultEncoding);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Saves data using the identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="identifier">Identifier.</param>
    /// <param name="data">data to save.</param>
    /// <param name="saveFile"> Save File Number</param>
    /// <param name="encode">Encrypt the data?</param>
    /// <param name="password">Encryption Password.</param>
    /// <param name="serializer">Serializer.</param>
    /// <param name="encoding">Encoding.</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The 1st type parameter.</typeparam>
    public static void Save<T>(string identifier, T data, int saveFile, bool encode, string password, ISaveSystemSerializer serializer, Encoding encoding)
    {
        if (!Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageWrite) ||
            Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageRead))
        {
            Permission.RequestUserPermissions(new []{Permission.ExternalStorageRead, Permission.ExternalStorageWrite } );
            Debug.Log("Permission Granted"); 
        }
        
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(identifier)) throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(identifier));
        
        serializer ??= Serializer;
        encoding ??= DefaultEncoding;
        string filePath = "";
            
        
        if (identifier == "Settings")
        {
            filePath = $"{Path}/{identifier + ".cfg"}";
        }
        else
        {
            filePath = $"{Path}/{identifier}{saveFile:D3}.vrm";
        }

        
            
        data ??= default(T);
        Stream stream = null;

        
        if (encode)
        {
            stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        }
        else
        {
            stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        }
        
        serializer.Serialize(data, stream, encoding);
        
        stream.Dispose();
        Debug.Log("saved" + filePath);
            
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads data using identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="identifier">Identifier.</param>
    /// <param name="saveSlot"> The save slot to load from</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The 1st type parameter.</typeparam>
    public static T Load<T>(string identifier, int saveSlot)
    {
        return Load<T>(identifier, saveSlot, default(T), Encode, EncodePassword, Serializer, DefaultEncoding);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads data using identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="identifier">Identifier.</param>
    /// <param name="saveSlot"> the save slot to load from</param>
    /// <param name="defaultValue">Default Value.</param>
    /// <param name="encode">Load encrypted data? (set it to true if you have used encryption in save)</param>
    /// <param name="password">Encryption Password.</param>
    /// <param name="serializer">Serializer.</param>
    /// <param name="encoder">Encoder.</param>
    /// <param name="encoding">Encoding.</param>
    /// <param name="path">Path.</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The 1st type parameter.</typeparam>
    public static T Load<T>(string identifier, int saveSlot, T defaultValue, bool encode, string password, ISaveSystemSerializer serializer, Encoding encoding)
    {
            
        if (!Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageRead))
        {
            Permission.RequestUserPermissions(new []{Permission.ExternalStorageRead, Permission.ExternalStorageWrite } );
            Debug.Log("Permission Granted");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(identifier))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(identifier));
            
        serializer ??= Serializer;
        encoding ??= DefaultEncoding;
        defaultValue ??= default(T);
            
        T result = defaultValue;
        string filePath = "";
            
        if (identifier == "Settings") 
            filePath = $"{Path}/{identifier + ".cfg"}";
        else
            filePath = $"{Path}/{identifier}{saveSlot:D3}.vrm";
            
        if (Exists(identifier, saveSlot))
        {
            Stream stream = null;
            stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            result = serializer.Deserialize<T>(stream, encoding);
            stream.Dispose();
            Debug.Log("loaded" + filePath);
            return result;
        }
        return default;
    }

        
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks whether the specified identifier exists or not.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="identifier">Identifier.</param>
    /// <param name="saveSlot"> The save slot to load from</param>
    public static bool Exists(string identifier, int saveSlot) => 
        File.Exists($"{Path}/{identifier}{saveSlot:D3}.vrm");
            

    /// <summary>
    /// Delete the specified identifier and path.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="identifier">Identifier.</param>
    /// <param name="saveSlot"> the save slot to load from </param>
    /// <param name="path">Path.</param>
    public static void Delete(string identifier, int saveSlot)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(identifier))
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(identifier));
            
        string filePath = "";
        if (identifier == "Settings") 
            filePath = $"{Path}/{identifier + ".cfg"}";
        else
            filePath = $"{Path}/{identifier}{saveSlot:D3}.vrm";
            
        if (!Exists(filePath, saveSlot)) return;
        File.Delete(filePath);
    }
   
}
```

I tried loading the file using unity's AndroidJavaClass but i don't understand java :)
Even though i managed to come up with something it didn't work at all.

Comment: It would have been more useful if you specified what permissions exactly you set.

Answer (score 0):

I do not work with Unity but I think, this issue is the same for multiple game engines, regarding the Meta Quest 2.

What I did to make file access work with System.IO C# classes, given that it is set up to work with remote debug already:

- Set "Read External Storage" and "Write External Storage" Permissions in the export settings.
- Once the app has been debugged/started remotely on the glasses, go into the Meta Quest 2 settings, in "Apps > Permissions > Storage" and then the app name to allow file access for your application.
- Use `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<javaPackageName>/files/…` as filepath. Apparently, other files cannot be modified.
- If it still doesn't work, connect the glasses to a computer and explicitly copy over the files into `internal storage…/Android/data/<javaPackageName>/files` of the Meta Quest 2. Actually, the game editor should do it already when remote-debugging your game but this is a safe way for testing without missing files.

##### Sources:

- [Accessing storage on Android with Godot Apps - Godot Forums](https://godotforums.org/d/20894-accessing-storage-on-android-with-godot-apps)
- [I want to read a file inside Movies which is a pub... - Meta Community Forums - 958524](https://communityforums.atmeta.com/t5/Quest-Development/I-want-to-read-a-file-inside-Movies-which-is-a-public-folder-in/td-p/958524)